# Error when running my app on localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, localhost

I'm currently working on a ruby on rails app, rails 4.

I made some changes and have begun using a single table inheritance, which has evidently caused the issues.

Here's the console print out:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3113ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `seller’ for #<User:0x00000105b10318>):
    81:             <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    82:             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    83:                 <%= render_navigation :context => (current_user.blank? ? :guest : :user) %>
    84:                 <%= render_navigation :expand_all => true, :context => :auth %>
    85:             </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    86:         </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    87:     </nav>
  app/views/layouts/home.html.erb:84:in `_app_views_layouts_home_html_erb___658910842130911230_2169593320'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:7:in `main
```

As a new coder I can only guess there is some issue with a user that is stored somewhere using the old method to store them as a `Seller`. We are now using single table inheritance for the `Seller`, this being:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  class Seller < User; end
```

- If I am correct where are these users stored? I'm running this using the `Rails S` command
- If I'm wrong please feel free to slap me on the wrist and please point me in the right direction! :)

Thanks :D

Comment: is this the full code for the `User` class and `Seller` class?

Comment: That is not the full code for the User class. There are around 40 lines of additional code. Thanks for your input Uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-First of all you need to add a class column to your users table (it's better to avoid the type column because it's already used by rails): `rails g migration AddClassToUsers class:string`

-run `rake db:migrate`

-In your user model add:

```
self.inheritance_column = :class
```

(this will specify the column for sti)

and:

```
def self.classes
    %w(Seller)
 end
```

*So later you can do as follows:*

```
def self.classes
    %w(Seller Buyer Guest)
 end
```

-remove this line from the user model:

```
class Seller < User; end
```

-create the seller model file in the models folder:

```
# app/models/seller.rb 
class Seller < User; end
```

For more details you really need to follow this blog post: http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/

Hope this will help

Comment: Just a quick question, if you check out the following [link](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/) "Note that `self.inheritance_column = :race` is used to specify the column for STI and is not necessary if you are using the default column type." I was not made aware of specifying the column for STI in other documentation. Is it truly necessary and what difference does it make if I leave it out? Thanks a lot @Badoo I'm learning lots! :D

Comment: If you don't name it, it will look for the type column. However I named the column "type" once and things got complicated and caused bugs so I prefer to give the column another name. The column (I believe at least) is necessary, otherwise rails has no way to determine the animal sub models (in your case the seller model). There might be an other way to do that but that guide helped me a lot and I really recommend it, it's full of details (you should check out part 2 and 3 as well) Good luck with your coding !

Comment: Actually I didn't think about it when I wrote my answer but naming the column class isn't wise either.

Comment: so just keep the column as `type`?

Comment: To avoid any confusion I'd call the column `usertype` or `userclass`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to ruby on rails I don't recommend you to use single table inheritance, a lot of things are going to break (such as links, forms, controller's actions, etc...) and to repair them you should understand the basics of the framework. So what I recommend you to do is to simply add a boolean column to the users table:

```
rails g migration AddSellerToUsers seller:boolean
```

This will be easier to maintain and will allow you to verify if a user is a seller so that in your views you can do:

```
<% if current_user.seller? %>
# show things that are specific to sellers
<% end %>
```

If you really want to use single table inheritance here's a great tutorial that will help you understand how things work: http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/

Comment: Although I am new to Ruby on Rails, I should be ok fixing the links. I've already edited all of the links I believe need fixing. That error has been thrown up and I'm interested to know whether anyone knows how it has been caused? Thanks @Badoo